# Why sqlite3_data_count() returns 0 if the db contains data?

Tags: c, sqlite

I've got a sqlite database with the following data:

```
[ouhma@testing ~]$ sqlite3 /home/ouhma/test.db "select col1, col2 from mytable;"
201507|9063104793
201507|9212527372
201507|9212533474
201507|9212575626
201507|9212576618
201507|9212587832
201507|9322355921
201507|9322743536
201507|9334886428
201507|9334901403
```

But when I try to do the same query running under a C program by this way:

```
if (sqlite3_open(filedb, &db) != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening db: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

char * sql = "select col1, col2 from mytable;";

iret = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
if (iret != SQLITE_OK) {
    printf("Error SQLITE %d when preparing the query.\n", iret);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

ncolumns = sqlite3_data_count(stmt);
printf("Columns: %d\n", ncolumns);

if (ncolumns == 0) {
    printf("No data :(\n");
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

...
```

Instead of returning the same rows as before, the data count is zero, and then I cant not retrieve the information that I need.

```
[ouhma@testing ~]$ /home/ouhma/querydb2 /home/ouhma/query.txt /home/ouhma/test.db /home/ouhma/output.txt
Columns: 0
No data :(
```

I've checked [some C examples](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitec/), and the prepare statement looks ok.

So what am I dismissing? Why is it returning 0 rows if the db contains data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/data_count.html) says:

> The sqlite3_data_count(P) interface returns the number of columns in the current row of the result set of prepared statement P. If prepared statement P does not have results ready to return … then sqlite3_data_count(P) returns 0.

There is no current row; the statement does not have results ready to return because you never executed it (with [sqlite3_step()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html)).

Comment: Thank you so much. The statement that I needed was `sqlite3_column_count` not `sqlite3_data_count`